# Change SERVER'S Home FTP SSL Certificate with Powershell

Tags: powershell, ssl, iis, ftp

***First, let me point out that I'm NOT referring to the Default Site but the server's "Home" (as IIS refers to it). Thanks.***

---

I have one public IP address and in IIS 3 websites and 2 FTP sites. Not a problem, thanks to named bindings. However, IIS is a little broken when it comes to "correctly" choosing the path/certificate on said named bindings. I can't remember the link I used but you must specify the FTP SSL certificate at "Home" level **AND** at site level in order to establish a secure FTP connection.

I use Certify to manage/renew my SSL certificates. Because of the above issue; I create a single certificate, which includes both subdomains, and update one FTP site. I then have a task that runs on success which pushes the new certificate to the other FTP site on completion (below is a copy of the file).

```
Import-Module WebAdministration
$configItem = 'ftpServer.security.ssl.serverCertHash'
$thumb = Get-ItemProperty "IIS:\Sites\FTP 1" -Name ftpServer.security.ssl.serverCertHash.Value
Set-ItemProperty "IIS:\Sites\Default Web Site" -Name $configItem -Value $thumb
Set-ItemProperty "IIS:\Sites\FTP 2" -Name $configItem -Value $thumb
```

As you can see it sets the FTP SSL certificate for the "Default Web Site" as well - just to attempt it as a fix. However, this is not what I need. What I need to do is set the top-level "Home" FTP SSL certificate from Powershell, which is navigable as shown below.

[image: IIS navigation to the "Home" FTP SSL certificate]

I tried searching for a command, tried a couple that I thought might work, but have been unsuccessful thus far.

Thanks in advance

Comment: It seems that powershell only can set certificate of site instead of top-level "Home". Powershell changed the setting of applicationhost.config file to change the site setting. But certificates arenot set in applicationhost.config file. So you need to specific site so that can set certificate.

Comment: Damn, that's a shame. I thought as much from my research - though I was hoping for some miracle command I missed. I have opened an issue on github to see if this is something they can even add. (https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShellModuleCoverage/issues/23)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, after a lot more rummaging, I managed to find a way to do it.

###### TLDR;

The new PowerShell script is:

```
Import-Module WebAdministration
$configItem = 'ftpServer.security.ssl.serverCertHash'
$thumb = Get-ItemProperty "IIS:\Sites\FTP 1" -Name ftpServer.security.ssl.serverCertHash.Value
Set-ItemProperty "IIS:\Sites\FTP 2" -Name $configItem -Value $thumb
C:\windows\system32\inetsrv\appcmd.exe set config -section:system.applicationHost/sites /siteDefaults.ftpServer.security.ssl.serverCertHash:"$thumb" /commit:apphost
```

---

So while researching I found a Microsoft article on [FTP Over SSL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/publish/using-the-ftp-service/using-ftp-over-ssl-in-iis-7#:%7E:text=%25SystemRoot%25%5CSystem32%5Cinetsrv%5Cconfig), it mentions the applicationHost.config (also mentioned by @BruceZhang). After scrolling through that I found `<siteDefaults>` which is just after the last `</site>`. In there there was the a property for the SSL certificate (path "`<ftpServer>`/`<security>`/`<ssl>`"). Some more rummaging and I found `appcmd` which can be used to update this config file. Lo and behold, I produced the above (last line) updated PowerShell script.